# Specifying a xor condition between two EAttribute in EMF

Tags: java, plugins, emf

I have situation where I have to use XOR operation between two given nodes. For given tag say  I can have 2 child tag. or  not both. ie

```
<parent>
    <child1> </child1>
</parent>
```

or

```
<parent>
    <child2> </child2>
</parent>
```

is allowed.

How can I specify this in EMF ecore or genmodel.

In XSD   can be used. What is the equivalent in EMF?

I tried generating emf gen model out of the xsd with such condition but I didnt realize how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

In EMF there is Feature Map for that case. You may read this [article](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/docs/overviews/FeatureMap.pdf)
which explains its technical details.